# Using an Android phone or tablet as a keyboard or mouse

Tags: raspbian, input-device, android

There are [many remote apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=xbmc&c=apps) to let Android devices control XBMC installations.  Is there anything that would act as a generic keyboard or mouse, to allow an Android phone to control [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/), [ChameleonPI](http://chameleon.enging.com/), or any other distribution?

Comment: This is something I've been thinking about doing, using `uinput` on the linux side.  I won't have time for a few months tho :/

Comment: Simple Computer Remote supports Raspberry Pi https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rekap.remote#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLnJla2FwLnJlbW90ZSJd

Comment: Are you looking for an application (I can refer you to those) or for an API which you can use to code your own solution. If nothing currently exists, I am sure that you could cajole some people to help you in this endeavor.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx Looking for an app at this time.  Although, if an API could be used to create a custom keyboard with a button layout similar to, say, a Super Nintendo controller...

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll have to try it out next weekend when I get my Android phone back.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi Remote Control uses SSH to controll the RPi. Configuration seems to be limited and you cannot change the audio output. I need to use a USB DAC so this probably won't be useful.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raspberry.remote&hl=en

NetIO looks good, I'm trying it out now.
http://store.raspberrypi.com/projects/netio

Both of them seem to be targetted at media applications.

Answer (score 0):

With default/commonly preinstalled software i think it is not possible.

However, I am using "anyremote", and you can install this command line package +Graphical interface (ganyremote/kanyremote). g= gnome and k= kde

By the way this package is available in most linux default repositories, including raspberryOS or Ubuntu.

So, you just need  to type: *sudo apt-get install anyremote*
or use your graphical package manager

You can download the android app from official page:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/anyremote/files/anyremote-android-client/

From same domain you can also download the server/daemon
http://anyremote.sourceforge.net/dload.html